# If the tangent plane of sphere $x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2=25$ cuts the intercepts $a,b,c$ from axes prove that $25(1/a^2+1/b^2+1/c^2)=(2/c-1)^2$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

This is a problem of 3D Geometry. This following question appears in "A Text Book On Co-Ordinate Geometry With Vector Analysis" by Rahman & Bhattacharjee ; Chapter 4 - Exercise 37

If the tangent plane of sphere $\;x^2 + y^2 +(z -2)^2 = 25\;$ cuts the intercepts $\;a,\,b,\,c\;$ from axes prove that,

$25\left(\dfrac1{a^2}+\dfrac1{b^2}+\dfrac1{c^2}\right)=\left(\dfrac2c-1\right)^2$.

I have tried to prove that myself.
My progress:
I transformed the sphere into a tangent plane form through point P($x_0,y_0,z_0$).
Then, the equation of the sphere transforms to,
$xx_0 +yy_0 +z(z_0 -2) =21+2z_0$
What should I do next?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Compute the equation of the plane tangent at generic point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ belonging to the sphere ; then transform this equation into the form $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$ where $a,b,c$ are the intercepts with axes as in your text.

Comment: Please, use the advice I gave you and insert your progress into your question. If such is this case, we will help you.

Comment: I have Updated the question and i have tried to take your solution into consideration but that did not work.

Comment: See my answer. Btw, I wasn't aware of your last comment because you hadn't prefixed it by my pseudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the generic equation of your tangent plane in $x_0 \in S$ :

$$xx_0 +yy_0 +z(z_0 -2)=21+2z_0 \tag{1}$$

We have to keep in mind that $x_0 \in S$ if and only if :

$$x_0^2 + y_0^2 +(z_0 -2)^2 = 25 \tag{2}$$

The intercept $x=a$ of this tangent plane with $x$ axis is obtained by taking $y=z=0$ in (1) giving :

$$a=\frac{21+2z_0}{x_0}$$

Taking now $x=z=0$ in (1), we get the ordinate of the intercept of the plane with $y$ axis :

$$b=\frac{21+2z_0}{y_0}$$

For a similar reason :

$$c=\frac{21+2z_0}{z_0-2}$$

Now, if we compute the left hand side of the relationship you have to establish, we get :

$$25 \left(\frac{x_0^2 + y_0^2 +(z_0 -2)^2}{(21+2z_0)^2}\right)=25 \left(\frac{25}{(21+2z_0)^2}\right)$$

the second expression coming from (2).

which is indeed equal to the right hand side,

$$\left(\dfrac{2(z_0-1)}{21+2z_0}-1\right)^2$$

as you can check it.

Comment: Any comment ? ...